# How do I save a list of database models/entities as a field in a model (Django)?

Tags: django, django-models

This might be impossible, but I wonder if there's a way to save a list of model as part of another model. For example, suppose I have a model called `Group` defined as below:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Group Name", max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Then I have another model named `Message`, that is defined as below:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=160)
    composer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='composed_message')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # groups = a_list_of_group # How do I accomplish this?
```

I would like to add a field/column in the model `Message` above called `groups` that will point to multiple group entities. Is there a way to do this? What sort of DB relationship must be established between `Group` and `Message` to accomplish? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships).

A `ManyToManyField` in the `Message` model will mean that a `Message` can be posted in multiple `Groups` and a `Group` can have multiple `Message` objects.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=160)
    composer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='composed_message')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group) # add a 'ManyToManyField' for storing multiple groups
```

Here, a  model `Message` object now points to multiple `Group` entities.

To get all the groups for a particular message object `message_obj`, you can use below:

```
message_obj.groups.all() # lists all the groups for a particular message
```

**To save a group to `message_object`, you can do the following:**

We first create a group object `group_obj` (lets say). Then to save it we can use `.add()`.

```
message_object.groups.add(group_obj) # attach the group object to a message
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Rahul Gupta. What if I'd like to save a group to message_obj?

Comment: Thank you, Rahul. I accepted your answer because it's comprehensive and answers my question. :)

Comment: Note that, `message_object.save()` is not needed after a group was added to `message_object.groups`.

Comment: You are right, that step is not necessary. `.add()` calls `.save()` internally. Thanx. updated the ans.

Answer (score 1):

You need a ForeignKey from Group to Message

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Group Name", max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.Foreignkey(Groups, null=True, related_name="groups")
```

You can access these groups from a message instance as follows:

```
message.groups.all()
```

Note that this means one Group has only have one Message, and that one Message can have any number of groups. Is this what you desire?

Comment: thank you for the answer. My goal is to save individual message object with a bunch of groups associated (in other words, each message will have one-to-many groups that it must be sent). On the other hand, I do not want `Group` to be tied with `Message` because groups can/should be created without message object. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

@Mark Galloway gave you a good answer, but as he properly commented it is for the case when there is a `one to many` relationship between `Message` and `Group`. You could also have a `many to many` relation between `Message` and `Group`, and then you could use this:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=160)
    composer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='composed_message')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
```

Now you have more options ;).

Comment: Thank you, @Vladir Parrado Cruz. I think `ManyToMany` is more appropriate for my use case. That means if I want to add/save a group to `Message`, I could do `message_object.groups.add(group)`, right?

Comment: Thank you! :) I'll accept Rahul's answer above because his also included how to save and he answered slightly earlier than you did. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: No problem, the aim of this is that you get the problem solved ;), who gets the points is not so important ;). Thanks to let me know, it was a kind comment from you.